# Removing file / folder link after using "Save As..." then "Web Page, complete"

Tags: windows-xp, html

When you right-click save-as a web page in FF, the page is saved along with a folder containing any associated media that page needs (images, js, etc).

My problem is that I want to reorganise the associated media folder, but wherever I move this folder, the saved .html file is moved as well. ARGH!

I can rename each folder, which breaks the "link" between html file and media folder, but there must be a cleaner way to do it. Does anyone else know?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As I discovered, GAThrawn's answer is good if you have Office XP / 2003 installed on your system. If not, you need to jump into the registry by going to START -> Run, type `regedit` and in the registry editor, browse to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
```

Right-click in the left panel to create a new DWORD Value. Call it `NoFileFolderConnection` and give it a value of 1.

That's it! If you ever what to turn the linking on again, change `NoFileFolderConnection`'s value to 0.

Alternatively (if you're comfortable applying a registry edit via a downloaded file) you can find a downloadable solution [here](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/webpairs.htm) ([archived copy](https://archive.ph/u7nHB)).

More information can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/manage)

Comment: Link is dead `:(`

Answer (score 12):

Based on Microsoft's [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20150316165509/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/252721):

Another option which doesn't require registry modifications is simply to rename the HTML file or the folder.

When trying to rename the file/folder, the following message will appear:

> Rename Warning! If you rename this file, it will no longer belong to
> the folder Test_files. To rename it safely, open the file, save it
> with a new name, and then delete the folder Test_files. Do you want to
> rename this file anyway?

After approving it, the connection between the html file to the files folder will be removed. Now, you can delete/move the folder. After you've done you can rename the file's name back to its original name.

Comment: This appears to just repeat what the question already said in its last paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

@Pavium is right, this is a Windows setting not a Firefox setting that stops you separating the folder from the file easily. Firefox does have an option to save just the HTML page without the associated media ("Save Page As, then select "Web page, HTML only") but it doesn't sound like that's what you're asking about.

To stop Windows linking the file and folder permanently, open up Windows Explorer (not Internet Explorer), click <kbd>Tools</kbd> menu, <kbd>Options</kbd>, click the <kbd>View</kbd> tab, then scroll about halfway down the Advanced Settings box, you should see a "Managing pairs of Web pages and folders" which is probably set to "Show both parts but manage as a single file" at the moment, you probably want to select "Show both parts and manage them individually".

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to find the relevant checkbox in the Advanced Settings panel. Are those instructions for winXP?

Comment: Yeah I was sitting on a WinXP Pro box at work as I typed that. There isn't a single checkbox, there's 3 "radio" buttons. See this screenshot (from XP) http://www.jard.co.uk/random/su/ManageHTM.PNG

Comment: Doh! I must be missing an update, because I've got a big fat nothing where those options are...

Comment: That's strange, I've just checked a few XP VMs that I've got lying around with a mixture of SP2 & SP3, IE6 & IE7 and they've all got that option. Are you on a company PC? Do they use Group Policies? It may be that your admin has removed that option using a group policy (I know we hide certain parts of the Connections tab).

Comment: I might have just tracked down why I dont have the option; http://windowsxp.mvps.org/webpairs.htm

Comment: Ah, sorry, never occurred to me that this option comes with Office! All the machines I looked at that had this option do have either Office XP or 2003, so that could be it. Guess we all learnt something

Answer (score 0):

I saw something, maybe in Folder Options, which lets you set a general policy for this relationship between HTML file and `_files` folder.

I'm not sitting in front of Windows at the moment, so I can't check my rather hazy memory.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so if I understand correctly. You have a complete web page that you have saved. All the files link to:

```
href="saved%20website/css_002.css"
```

and you want to move the folder and have all the links not break?

If so, I think all you have to do is open the .htm file in a text editor like notepad++ do a find and replace with the new path on this part:

```
saved%20website/
```

It will replace all of the urls that have broken.

Comment: Nope, you've misunderstood. GAThrawn is spot-on, it just seems that I don't have the right menu option available in XP