# Imitate saved web page behavior in explorer (linked file and folder)

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

When saving a web page a `page.html` file and `page_files` folder are created and are linked together.

How does it work? Is it possible to imitate this behavior for custom file types?
If it's possible, can it be applied by changing settings (file/registry/etc) that maybe linked to an executable/script that checks the connection, or an external program is needed to create and handle it?

I'd like to get information about this behavior, and possible explanation of how it works, limitations etc. Thanks!

[image]

[image] [image]

<sup>I'm using Windows 10 (1803), but it exists in multiple previous Windows versions, as far as I can remember.</sup>

Comment: Posted the original comment as an answer. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, it might be built into Explorer as a simple check specifically for HTML files.

Currently, you can create any folder with `_file` or `_files` at the end and, assuming there is a similarly named item ending in `.htm` or `.html` (regardless if it is actually an HTML file), the two items will be "associated" as long as that naming scheme is kept.

---

*Note that this [Super User answer](https://superuser.com/questions/103280/removing-file-folder-link-after-using-save-as-then-web-page-complete) seems to confirm it is based around Explorer (and has been around since at least Windows 2000 according to this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717448/reason-why-folder-associated-with-saved-webpage-gets-deleted-when-we-delete-save)).*

*Tangentially, while the option to toggle this association on and off was apparently dropped in Windows Vista, this [Microsoft Answers forum post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/delete-html-file-without-deleting-resource-files/295d8767-b6fa-4e65-ad87-ff8bae659811) details a registry hack to re-enable the toggling feature (which is based around Explorer). Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to provide any clues about creating new type associations.*

---