# Windows deletes HTML files when I delete a folder

Tags: windows, ntfs, file-management, html

I have saved a HTML web page. I got a `.html` file along with a folder which has the same name. Both of these seem to be linked magically:

- if I delete the HTML file, the folder gets deleted as well
- if I delete the folder, the HTML file gets deleted as well

The question is 2-fold:

1. how do I delete the folder without deleting the HTML file?
2. how does that technically work? How does Windows or NTFS perform the necessary linking?

I'm on Windows 7 SP1 x64, all updates. The files were saved using Firefox 61.0.1. However, on the disk, it's shown as a "Chrome HTML Document".

Comment: You cannot they are linked and will not work independently of each other.

Comment: If you make copies of both, are they still linked?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717448/reason-why-folder-associated-with-saved-webpage-gets-deleted-when-we-delete-save and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/delete-html-file-without-deleting-resource-files/295d8767-b6fa-4e65-ad87-ff8bae659811

Comment: @Moab: I edited the HTML file so that it does not need files.

Answer (score 11):

> How do I delete the folder without deleting the HTML file?

**Explorer**

Rename the folder before deleting it. This includes:

- Removing the `_files` portion of the name at the end of the folder.
- Renaming some portion of the main folder name (i.e. what comes before `_files`).
- Changing the folder name all together.

**Command Prompt**

You can use something like e.g.:

```
rmdir "example-html-dir_files" /s
```

Note that this will prompt you to confirm removal of the directory. Since some pages are saved with long titles, you can optionally use `dir /x` to get the DOS 8.1 short name for the directory ahead of time (as needed).

> How does that technically work? How does Windows or NTFS perform the necessary linking?

---

*Warning: Suppositions Ahead!*

*Note, however, this [Super User answer for Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/103280/removing-file-folder-link-after-using-save-as-then-web-page-complete) (provided helpfully in the comments) seems to confirm this behavior is based around Explorer itself. This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717448/reason-why-folder-associated-with-saved-webpage-gets-deleted-when-we-delete-save) indicates this behavior has been around since Windows 2000 and applies to (at least) Copy, Cut, Paste, Move, Delete and Send To.*

---

While this is admittedly a guess, it seems that this behavior may be something specific to Explorer.

As evidence, these files/folders only seem linked in Explorer (they aren't apparently linked on the command line) and are only "linked" if they:

1. Have (relatively speaking) the *exact* same names.
2. End with some combination of `.htm`, `.html` (for files) or `_file`, `_files` (for folders).

Furthermore, it seems possible to rename *any* file with e.g. `.htm`, create a new folder with the same name with e.g. `_files` at the end and they will then apparently exhibit the same "linked" behavior automatically (e.g. deleted together, etc).

> The files were saved using Firefox 61.0.1. However, on the disk, it's shown as a "Chrome HTML Document".

It sounds as if Chrome is set as your default browser and is associated with `.htm` and `.html` files.

Comment: It’s called “_file connection_.” A Windows-specific (or probably `explorer.exe`-specific) feature. [Here’s the document.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/manage#connected-files)

Comment: It's proper BS that it can't be changed in the settings of either file or directory.

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper Honestly, I have never understood the reasoning behind not having an option. It seems like common sense to me, too.

Comment: It actually does have an option. It's documented in the link Константин Ван sent: by creating and setting to 1 the REG_DWORD at HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/NoFileFolderConnection

Comment: Good point. But by option, personally, I meant e.g. a simple toggle in the UI. It's worthwhile knowing Microsoft allows this association to be disabled, but digging around in the registry for a value that doesn't normally even exist probably hides this fact from many users.